# Git commands to switch to an arbitrary git repository/branch?

Tags: git

I've got some deployment scripts that automate cloning of a repository to a local dir. Unfortunately, I haven't found a good way to handle updates, so I just wipe out the local dir beforehand. This is clearly very wasteful.

Ideally, I want a sequence of commands that will guarantee a particular local directory becomes a copy of a specified repo/branch, with the minimum amount of data transfer required. So if the dir is already on the right repo/branch, it will simply update it. If it's on the right repo, but not the right branch, it will just switch to the new branch.

I'm sure there's a way to do this by examining some of the files in .git and performing specific actions depending on what is found, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way.

One important note is that any changes in the local dir can always be discarded.

There may be a question already that answers this, but I haven't been able to find the right wording to find it.

Comment: If you can add all of the repos as remotes to the local copy, you can `git fetch <remote>`, followed by `git checkout -f <remote-branch>`. *EDIT:* This works as an answer, I think. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ git fetch <url> <branch>      # get the most up-to-date version of that branch
                                #  (only downloads needed objects)

$ git checkout -f FETCH_HEAD    # force the working tree to match fetched branch
```

Note that this does leave old objects in the repo.  If at any point you want to **irreversibly** delete the unreferenced objects and clean the repository, you can run

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: This seems to do, thanks! It does potentially leave stuff lying around from the old repo/whatever, but I think that's fine for my purposes. I really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Yeah, that was something else I was going to comment about.  If you want to **irreversibly** delete old, unreferenced objects from the local repo, you can run `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` followed by `git gc --prune=now`.

Answer (score 0):

> One important note is that any changes in the local dir can always be discarded.

So first thing you need is:

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

> if the dir is already on the right repo/branch

I'm not sure what you mean by "the right repo", but I am guessing that would involve checking `pwd` against the directory you want and `cd` or whatever.

The interesting part however is the branch. Using the following command:

```
__git_ps1 "%s"
```

you get the current branch of git in the current repository (or nothing if it's not a git repository). There are also special outputs for the .git folder, bare repository, in the middle of merge etc.

You can then check the branch you are interested in with the output of this command to know if you are on the right branch. Although, it is much simpler if you just checkout the desired branch even if you are already on it.